# .htaccess 301 redirect remove category slug (Prestashop)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

I'm migrating a website from Prestashop 1.6 to Prestashop 1.7 and I need to add 301 redirects for product pages to htaccess. So the link structure is as follows:

**Old website:** 
https://example.com/lang/category-name/product-name.html

**New website:**
https://example.com/lang/product-name.html

The website has around 70 categories in each language. What would be the best way to redirect URLs to the new link structure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use any module to change product URLs?

Comment: Nope, I changed the URL structure in the Prestashop settings.

Answer (score 0):

i can try include in htaccess

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]